Optimise Utility function using autograd
Suppose i have a categorical variable $D~Cat(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ and then i have $U(D) = D^2-4D+4$. How can i use autograd and pytorch to minimise $U(D)$ w.r.t theta_1, theta_2?
I have tried the following code which converges to the correct answer of $\theta_3 = 1$.
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

# Define the function U(X)
def U(X):
    return X**2 - 4*X + 4

# Define a function to compute the expected value of U(X) given the probabilities
def expected_U(theta1, theta2, theta3):
    return theta1 * U(torch.tensor(0.0)) + theta2 * U(torch.tensor(1.0)) + theta3 * 
           U(torch.tensor(2.0))

# Initialize parameters randomly
theta1_raw = torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True)
theta2_raw = torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True)

# Define optimizer
optimizer = optim.Adam([theta1_raw, theta2_raw], lr=0.1)

# Number of optimization steps
num_steps = 1000

# Optimization loop
for step in range(num_steps):
    optimizer.zero_grad()

# Apply softplus to ensure positivity
    theta1 = F.softplus(theta1_raw)
    theta2 = F.softplus(theta2_raw)
    theta3 = 1 - theta1 - theta2

# Compute the expected value of U(X)
    loss = expected_U(theta1, theta2, theta3)

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()


# Retrieve optimized values
optimized_theta1 = theta1.item()
optimized_theta2 = theta2.item()
optimized_theta3 = 1 - optimized_theta1 - optimized_theta2

# Print optimized values
print("Optimized theta1:", optimized_theta1)
print("Optimized theta2:", optimized_theta2)
print("Optimized theta3:", optimized_theta3)
print("Minimum expected value of U(X):", expected_U(optimized_theta1, 
optimized_theta2, optimized_theta3).item())

Now when i try to import categorical distributions directly and replace the function expected_U with the following
import torch.distributions as distribution


# Define a function to compute the expected value of U(X) given the probabilities
def expected_U(theta1, theta2, theta3):
    probs = torch.tensor([theta1, theta2, theta3], requires_grad=True)
    X = distribution.Categorical(probs=probs)
    return theta1 * U(X.probs[0]) + theta2 * U(X.probs[1]) + theta3 * U(X.probs[2])

It no longer works because the initial code samples theta_3 values which are negative and not within the simplex $\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3 = 1$ is there any way to add this constraint so that i can import the distribution directly into the code and still get the an answer that converges to the correct answer?

I don't have a full answer, but if you're running into issues with negative probabilities, you can shift to working with log probs instead
